# Exam doc class: Is it possible to "no print" solutions AND remove the boxes?

Tags: exam, answers

In the mwe, I have commented out the print solutions command: `%\printanswers`.

As expected, this produced the questions with empty boxes underneath. The "answers" are actually step-by-step solutions resulting in large boxes as seen below.

[image]

Is it possible to comment out the print answers command AND remove the boxes? (Reason: to reclaim all the white space created by the empty boxes. Students show work on separate paper.)

Alternatively, should I create 2 versions: (1) questions only (i.e. without the code for solution boxes) (2) questions + step-by-step solutions like this one:

[image]

The exercises contain from 15 - 30 problems. So any suggestions for making the process more efficient are most appreciated.

Thanks very much for taking time to read and respond to my post!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
%\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Unit 13 A\&B Fractional Exponents}
       {}
       {Due 05/02/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
%\noindent 
\bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Change to fractional exponents.}}
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. }}
%% Prob #34
\task
$\dfrac{a^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}a^{1/2}}{a^{3/8}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{a^{(3/4\bm{+}1/2)}}{a^{3/8}}=\dfrac{a^{(3/4\bm{+}2/4)}}{a^{3/8}}$
\bigskip
$a^{(5/4\bm{-}3/8)}=$
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{7/8}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
%%
%% Problem #35
\task
$\dfrac{(b^{4/5}c^{3/4})\strut^{20}}{(b^{1/2}c)\strut^2}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{b^{(4/5\bm{\cdot}20)}c^{(3/4\bm{\cdot}{20})}}{b^{(1/2\bm{\cdot}2)}c^{(1\bm{\cdot}2)}}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{b^{16}c^{15}}{bc^2}=$
\colorbox{yellow}{$b^{15}c^{13}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
%%% Prob #36
\task
$\dfrac{(a^4b^6)\strut^{2/3}}{(a^{10}b^5)\strut^{1/5}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{a^{(4\bm{\cdot}2/3)}b^{(6\bm{\cdot}2/3)}}{a^{(10\bm{\cdot}1/5)}b^{(5\bm{\cdot}1/5)}}=\dfrac{a^{8/3}b^4}{a^2b^1}$
\bigskip
$a^{(8/3-6/3)}b^{(4-1)}=$
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{2/3}b^3$}
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
%%% Prob #37
\task
$\dfrac{(a^{24}b^{16})\strut^{3/4}}{(a^{10}b^{14})\strut^{1/2}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{a^{(24\bm{\cdot}3/4)}b^{(16\bm{\cdot}3/4)}}{a^{(10\bm{\cdot}1/2)}b^{(14\bm{\cdot}1/2)}}=\dfrac{a^{18}b^{12}}{a^5b^7}$
\bigskip
$a^{(18-5)}b^{(12-7)}=$
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{13}b^5$}
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
%%% Prob #38
\task
$\dfrac{(a^4b^{1/2})\strut^{2}(a^6b^4)\strut^{1/2}}{(ab^4)\strut^{1/2}(ab^2)\strut^{1/4}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{\bigl(a^{(4\bm{\cdot}2)}b^{(1/2\bm{\cdot}2)}\bigr)\bigl(a^{(6\bm{\cdot}1/2)}b^{(4\bm{\cdot}1/2)}\bigr)}{\bigl(a^{(1\bm{\cdot}1/2)}b^{(4\bm{\cdot}1/2)}\bigr)\bigl(a^{(1\bm{\cdot}1/4)}b^{(2\bm{\cdot}1/4}\bigr)}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{\bigl(a^8b^1\bigr)\bigl(a^3b^2\bigr)}{\bigl(a^{(1/2)}b^2\bigr)\bigl(a^{(1/4)}b^{(1/2)}\bigr)}$
\bigskip
$\dfrac{a^{(8+3)}b^{(1+2)}}{a^{(1/2+1/4)}b^{(2+1/2)}}=
\dfrac{a^{11}b^4}{a^{(3/4)}b^{(5/2)}}$
\bigskip
$a^{(11-3/4)}b^{(3-5/2)}=$\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{41/4}b^{1/2}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
%%% Prob #39
\task
$\biggl((a^2a^{1/2})\strut^2a\biggr)^{1/2}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\biggl((a^{2+1/2})\strut^2a\biggr)^{1/2}$
\bigskip
$\biggl((a^{5/2})\strut^2a\biggr)\strut^{1/2}=(a^5a)\strut^{1/2}$
\bigskip
$a^{(6\bm{\cdot}1/2)}$
=\colorbox{yellow}{$a^3$}
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are currently telling it to add a 5cm box when not printing solutions.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added code to test if solutions are being printed or not. In the second case, the boxes are removed.

Note that `[5cm]` was replaced by `[\SolutionSpace]` and `{\vspace{0.5cm}}` was commented out. Also use `\usepackage{color}` instead of `\usepackage{xcolor}` as required by the class `exam`.

With `%\printanswers`

[image: a]

With `\printanswers`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

%\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.

\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Unit 13 A\&B Fractional Exponents}
{}
{Due 05/02/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
    %\noindent 
    \bigskip
    \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother

%******************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\SolutionSpace}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{5cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
    \definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{0.8}}% solutions are printed
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{0cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
    \definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{1}}% solutions are not being printed
%*********************************************


\begin{document}
    %definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
    \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
    \begin{tasks}
        [style=enumerate](3)
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Change to fractional exponents.}}
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. }}
        %% Prob #34
        \task
        $\dfrac{a^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}a^{1/2}}{a^{3/8}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            $\dfrac{a^{(3/4\bm{+}1/2)}}{a^{3/8}}=\dfrac{a^{(3/4\bm{+}2/4)}}{a^{3/8}}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(5/4\bm{-}3/8)}=$
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{7/8}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%
        %% Problem #35
        \task
        $\dfrac{(b^{4/5}c^{3/4})\strut^{20}}{(b^{1/2}c)\strut^2}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            $\dfrac{b^{(4/5\bm{\cdot}20)}c^{(3/4\bm{\cdot}{20})}}{b^{(1/2\bm{\cdot}2)}c^{(1\bm{\cdot}2)}}$
            \bigskip
            $\dfrac{b^{16}c^{15}}{bc^2}=$
            \colorbox{yellow}{$b^{15}c^{13}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%% Prob #36
        \task
        $\dfrac{(a^4b^6)\strut^{2/3}}{(a^{10}b^5)\strut^{1/5}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            $\dfrac{a^{(4\bm{\cdot}2/3)}b^{(6\bm{\cdot}2/3)}}{a^{(10\bm{\cdot}1/5)}b^{(5\bm{\cdot}1/5)}}=\dfrac{a^{8/3}b^4}{a^2b^1}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(8/3-6/3)}b^{(4-1)}=$
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{2/3}b^3$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%% Prob #37
        \task
        $\dfrac{(a^{24}b^{16})\strut^{3/4}}{(a^{10}b^{14})\strut^{1/2}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            $\dfrac{a^{(24\bm{\cdot}3/4)}b^{(16\bm{\cdot}3/4)}}{a^{(10\bm{\cdot}1/2)}b^{(14\bm{\cdot}1/2)}}=\dfrac{a^{18}b^{12}}{a^5b^7}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(18-5)}b^{(12-7)}=$
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{13}b^5$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%% Prob #38
        \task
        $\dfrac{(a^4b^{1/2})\strut^{2}(a^6b^4)\strut^{1/2}}{(ab^4)\strut^{1/2}(ab^2)\strut^{1/4}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            $\dfrac{\bigl(a^{(4\bm{\cdot}2)}b^{(1/2\bm{\cdot}2)}\bigr)\bigl(a^{(6\bm{\cdot}1/2)}b^{(4\bm{\cdot}1/2)}\bigr)}{\bigl(a^{(1\bm{\cdot}1/2)}b^{(4\bm{\cdot}1/2)}\bigr)\bigl(a^{(1\bm{\cdot}1/4)}b^{(2\bm{\cdot}1/4}\bigr)}$
            \bigskip
            $\dfrac{\bigl(a^8b^1\bigr)\bigl(a^3b^2\bigr)}{\bigl(a^{(1/2)}b^2\bigr)\bigl(a^{(1/4)}b^{(1/2)}\bigr)}$
            \bigskip
            $\dfrac{a^{(8+3)}b^{(1+2)}}{a^{(1/2+1/4)}b^{(2+1/2)}}=
            \dfrac{a^{11}b^4}{a^{(3/4)}b^{(5/2)}}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(11-3/4)}b^{(3-5/2)}=$\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{41/4}b^{1/2}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%% Prob #39
        \task
        $\biggl((a^2a^{1/2})\strut^2a\biggr)^{1/2}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            $\biggl((a^{2+1/2})\strut^2a\biggr)^{1/2}$
            \bigskip
            $\biggl((a^{5/2})\strut^2a\biggr)\strut^{1/2}=(a^5a)\strut^{1/2}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(6\bm{\cdot}1/2)}$
            =\colorbox{yellow}{$a^3$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

**NOTE.** If your students will always use a separate answer sheet, you can remove all occurrences of `[\SolutionSpace]`. It is an optional argument in case you want to reserve a space below the question to write the solution.

So the code can be simplified.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.

\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Unit 13 A\&B Fractional Exponents}
{}
{Due 05/02/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
    %\noindent 
    \bigskip
    \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother

%******************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<
\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}
{\colorsolutionboxes \definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{0.8}}% solutions are printed
{\nocolorsolutionboxes} % solutions are not beign printed
%*********************************************


\begin{document}
    %definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
    \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
    \begin{tasks}
        [style=enumerate](3)
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Change to fractional exponents.}}
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. }}
        %% Prob #34
        \task
        $\dfrac{a^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}a^{1/2}}{a^{3/8}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}
            $\dfrac{a^{(3/4\bm{+}1/2)}}{a^{3/8}}=\dfrac{a^{(3/4\bm{+}2/4)}}{a^{3/8}}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(5/4\bm{-}3/8)}=$
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{7/8}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%
        %% Problem #35
        \task
        $\dfrac{(b^{4/5}c^{3/4})\strut^{20}}{(b^{1/2}c)\strut^2}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}
            $\dfrac{b^{(4/5\bm{\cdot}20)}c^{(3/4\bm{\cdot}{20})}}{b^{(1/2\bm{\cdot}2)}c^{(1\bm{\cdot}2)}}$
            \bigskip
            $\dfrac{b^{16}c^{15}}{bc^2}=$
            \colorbox{yellow}{$b^{15}c^{13}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%% Prob #36
        \task
        $\dfrac{(a^4b^6)\strut^{2/3}}{(a^{10}b^5)\strut^{1/5}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}
            $\dfrac{a^{(4\bm{\cdot}2/3)}b^{(6\bm{\cdot}2/3)}}{a^{(10\bm{\cdot}1/5)}b^{(5\bm{\cdot}1/5)}}=\dfrac{a^{8/3}b^4}{a^2b^1}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(8/3-6/3)}b^{(4-1)}=$
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{2/3}b^3$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%% Prob #37
        \task
        $\dfrac{(a^{24}b^{16})\strut^{3/4}}{(a^{10}b^{14})\strut^{1/2}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}
            $\dfrac{a^{(24\bm{\cdot}3/4)}b^{(16\bm{\cdot}3/4)}}{a^{(10\bm{\cdot}1/2)}b^{(14\bm{\cdot}1/2)}}=\dfrac{a^{18}b^{12}}{a^5b^7}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(18-5)}b^{(12-7)}=$
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{13}b^5$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%% Prob #38
        \task
        $\dfrac{(a^4b^{1/2})\strut^{2}(a^6b^4)\strut^{1/2}}{(ab^4)\strut^{1/2}(ab^2)\strut^{1/4}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}
            $\dfrac{\bigl(a^{(4\bm{\cdot}2)}b^{(1/2\bm{\cdot}2)}\bigr)\bigl(a^{(6\bm{\cdot}1/2)}b^{(4\bm{\cdot}1/2)}\bigr)}{\bigl(a^{(1\bm{\cdot}1/2)}b^{(4\bm{\cdot}1/2)}\bigr)\bigl(a^{(1\bm{\cdot}1/4)}b^{(2\bm{\cdot}1/4}\bigr)}$
            \bigskip
            $\dfrac{\bigl(a^8b^1\bigr)\bigl(a^3b^2\bigr)}{\bigl(a^{(1/2)}b^2\bigr)\bigl(a^{(1/4)}b^{(1/2)}\bigr)}$
            \bigskip
            $\dfrac{a^{(8+3)}b^{(1+2)}}{a^{(1/2+1/4)}b^{(2+1/2)}}=
            \dfrac{a^{11}b^4}{a^{(3/4)}b^{(5/2)}}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(11-3/4)}b^{(3-5/2)}=$\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{41/4}b^{1/2}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        %%% Prob #39
        \task
        $\biggl((a^2a^{1/2})\strut^2a\biggr)^{1/2}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}
            $\biggl((a^{2+1/2})\strut^2a\biggr)^{1/2}$
            \bigskip
            $\biggl((a^{5/2})\strut^2a\biggr)\strut^{1/2}=(a^5a)\strut^{1/2}$
            \bigskip
            $a^{(6\bm{\cdot}1/2)}$
            =\colorbox{yellow}{$a^3$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
%%      {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's an optional argument.  Just remover it.

Comment: @simondispa Perfect solution and a huge time saver! I'm a wee bit disappointed at how long it took me to type the 39 problems in this exercise set. But I'll get faster with practice (I hope). I completely agree with your comment about trying to squeeze too many numbers into a 3 column layout. Better to use 2 cols and increase font size. Thanks very much for all your suggestions!

Comment: @simondispa  I've bolixed something up when I copied my math problems after your code. The result: a color error. If you have time, perhaps you could look at this question I posted re: the color error: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684874/exam-class-solution-box-color-error-when-printing-answers   Thanks very much!  PS In writing my new post, I tried to make it clear that the error is strictly down to me.